# isolation of zeros of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, roots

Dears,

Assume $C\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a convex and compact set (say, a hyper-cube), and $f:C\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous.

Somebody know a result on the isolation and/or location of the zeros of $f$? There are many results for the case that $f$ be of complex variable and analytic, but I do not find nothing for the "real case", and assuming only the continuity of $f$.

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: A real analytic function will still have isolated zeros, but you can have a limit point of zeros for certain continuous and even differentiable functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can say in the general case because

> Every closed set in a metric space is the zero set of a continuous real function.

Indeed, if $X$ is a metric space and $C \subseteq X$ is closed, then $f(x)=d(x,C)$ is a continuous function $X \to \mathbb R$ such that $C = f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. You are right. But, if we assume f is Lipschitzian?

Comment: @user123043, just replace *closed* by *compact* for instance.

Comment: @user123043 The function $d(x,C)$ _is_ Lipschitz.